# Traceback class is not defined

Tags: python

I have a project in progress which references several classes from within other classes.

code:

```py
try:
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
except:
    input('Please install PyQt5 before using the GUI system. (press enter to close)')
    exit()

class app(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super(app, self).__init__([])
        print('running')
        andGate = gate()
        andGate.config('and', 2)

    def initUI(self):
        newAndBtn = QPushButton(self)
        newOrBtn = QPushButton(self)
        newXorBtn = QPushButton(self)

    def newAndGate(self):
        pass

class gate():
    gateType = 'none'
    _in = []
    _out = pinOut()

    def _init__(self):
        _in.append(pinIn())
        _in.append(pinIn())
        pass

    def config(self, gateType, inputTargets):
        #just some safety checks
        if gateType not in supportedGates:
            return False

        self.gateType = gateType
        if type(inputTargets) is not list:
            return False

        for i in inputTargets:
            if type(i) is not pinOut:
                return False

        self.gateType = gateType
        for i in range(len(self._in)):
            self._in[i].point(inputTargets[i])

    def update(self):
        if _in[0].fetch() and _in[1].fetch():
            _out.set(True)
        else:
            _out.set(False)
        print("update for {}".format(self))

class pinIn():
    value = True
    reference = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def point(target):
        if type(target) is not connOut:
            return False
        reference = target

    def fetch():
        self.value = reference.value
        return self.value

class pinOut():
    value = False

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set(self, newValue):
        if type(newValue) is not bool:
            return False
        self.value = newValue
```

when I create an instance of the app() class, I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python_Scripts\Logic\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main
  File "C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python_Scripts\Logic\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    class app(QApplication):
  File "C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python_Scripts\Logic\main.py", line 23, in app
    class gate():
  File "C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python_Scripts\Logic\main.py", line 26, in gate
    output = pinOut()
NameError: name 'pinOut' is not defined
```

I have tried moving the pinIn and pinout classes into the gate class, then moving them all into the app class, but none of this works. Before this, I had been declaring _in as a list containing two pinIn instances, but was getting the same error.

Why can't the gate class see the pinIn and pinout classes?

Comment: `gate._out` is a class attribute, created during the creation of the `gate` class - but `pinOut` has simply not been defined yet at that point in your code.  Moving the definition of `pinOut` to above `gate` would fix that, although I think the real error here is having this reference be a class attribute at all - it means that you can only ever create a single instance of `gate`, as any further instances would share the same inputs & output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `pinOut` is defined *after* you reference it:

```py
class gate():
    gateType = 'none'
    _in = []
    _out = pinOut()    # referenced here
    ...

class pinOut():        # defined here
    ...
```

Either move the definition of `pinOut` *before* the one of `gate` or, even better, set it in `__init__`:

```py
class gate():
    gateType = 'none'

    def __init__(self):
        self._in = [pinIn(), pinIn()]
        self._out = pinOut()
```

The reason why you should prefer initializing things in `__init__` is that this avoids sharing state between multiple instances, which is most likely what you want to avoid.

Comment: So this would explain why I can reference the gate class from the app class. I am call from a function within. I would guess all classes and definitions are loaded before any __init__ functions are called. I also presume the __init__ function in the app class is not getting called, due to the execution break. Thank you!

Comment: @AwesomeCronk: yes, things you put in the class body get executed immediately, while things you put in `__init__` get executed only when you instantiate the class. If you have some `__init__` in your code that is not getting executed, pay attention at typos (`_init__` vs `__init__`)